# How to add some js files to catalog product grid

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to add some js file to catalog product grid page in admin panel. For this I have tried below code in `.xml` file :

```
<adminhtml_catalog_product_index>
    <referense name="head">
        <action method="addJs"><script>admin/custom.js</script></action>
    </referense>
</adminhtml_catalog_product_index>
```

But above code not working, but when I add it in default section then it is added `custom.js` to all admin pages.

How to add js file to catalog product grid page in admin panel using xml?

Answer (score 1):

**Please use `</reference>` not `</referense>`**

```
<adminhtml_catalog_product_index>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addJs"><script>admin/custom.js</script></action>
    </reference>
</adminhtml_catalog_product_index>
```

You have typo mistake.

Comment: You can close this question after accept as answr.